# Rethrowing an exception in Android

Tags: android, try-catch, sqlexception

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I want to catch and re throw the same exception. I want to do this because I have to close a cursor before exit the method (a finally statement, isn't it?)

Can I do that? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just to close the cursor correctly, you can do a `try...finally` without a catch. That would be something like that :

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    // initialize and do things with the cursor
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're in an activity, you can use [`startManagingQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29); which will take care of your cursor lifecycle depending on the activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing if this is a good practice you can do this:

```
throw new YourException();
```